# SQL Missing Day Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am struggling to get desired result out details below

my source data is as

[Source data after joined to day dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qoJQ.png)

```
DATE_WID    PM_TOTAL    PM_WID
20150201    null    null
20150202    null    null
20150203    null    null
20150204    null    null
20150205    null    null
20150206    null    null
20150207    null    null
20150208    null    null
20150209    null    null
20150210    null    null
20150211    null    null
20150212    null    null
20150213    null    null
20150214    1   152
20150215    null    null
20150216    null    null
20150217    null    null
20150218    null    null
20150219    null    null
20150220    null    null
20150221    null    null
20150222    null    null
20150223    2   152
20150224    3   152
20150225    null    null
20150226    null    null
20150227    null    null
20150228    null    null
20150229    null    null
20150230    null    null
20150231    null    null
20150201    2   153
20150202    3   153
20150203    null    null
20150204    null    null
20150205    6   153
```

The result out is what I wanted is

[Result out desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7qpx.png)

```
DATE_WID    PM_TOTAL    PM_WID
20150201    0   152
20150202    0   152
20150203    0   152
20150204    0   152
20150205    0   152
20150206    0   152
20150207    0   152
20150208    0   152
20150209    0   152
20150210    0   152
20150211    0   152
20150212    0   152
20150213    0   152
20150214    1   152
20150215    1   152
20150216    1   152
20150217    1   152
20150218    1   152
20150219    1   152
20150220    1   152
20150221    1   152
20150222    1   152
20150223    2   152
20150224    3   152
20150225    3   152
20150226    3   152
20150227    3   152
20150228    3   152
20150229    3   152
20150230    3   152
20150231    3   152
20150201    2   153
20150202    3   153
20150203    3   153
20150204    3   153
20150205    6   153
```

Basically the data that I receive from the source is for the following `DATE_WID`:

20150214

20150223

20150224

For PM_WID 152

I had Left joined the source data with my calendar date for given month, hence the output what I get is all the days of the month – but the source data is shown for those days it had got into my system.

What I need is `PM_TOTAL` showing 14th value until following day where it’s null (as shown in the result output), but I need to show same `PM_WID` from first day of the month until last day of the month.

Please let me know if you need further details highly appreciate any help on this

Comment: Can you please post data in text format, not images

Comment: Can you also post the query you have used to generate your current output?

Comment: Why is the expected `PM_TOTAL` 3 when there are two entries for `20150224` and the second one is 6?

Comment: sorry the 20150224 was a error in my source data set - had attached the text file for source data and expected result out put the analytical function that i used was MAX(PM_TOTAL) (order by DATE_WID) did show some out put as expected but that not really right.....

Comment: How the source data is ordered ? Why a record `20150201    2   153` follows `20150231    null    null` ?